# Android BLE characteristicwrite

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I've been working on an android BLE project and tries to write remote characteristic.

When I use `BluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic()` to write remote characteristic,
the callback function `onCharacteristicWrite()` is invoked on local side, showing that it got `sendResponse()` from remote side

But on the remote side, the callback `onCharacteristicWriteRequest()` is not invoked.

I've checked the connection and it works fine, and there's no other functions that will call `sendResponse()` except `onCharacteristicWriteRequest()`

Anybody have idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provided any code it's hard to tell why this happens.

Anyhow, this is how is how it should look like;

```
// scan devices
...

// connect to server
device.connectGatt(..)
```

in callback **OnConnectionStateChanged** (client side)

```
if ( BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS != status ) {
    System.out.println("Connecting to server failed");
    return;
}

// discover services
bluetoothGatt.discoverServices()
```

in callback **OnServicesDiscovered** (client side)

```
if ( BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS != status ) {
    System.out.println("Could not discover services");
    return;
}

List<BluetoothGattService> services = bluetoothGatt.getServices();
for (BluetoothGattService service : services) {
    if ( MY_SERVICE_UUID == service.getUuid() ) {
        System.out.println("Found my service on this server");

        // get characteristic from service
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic myCharacteristic = service.getCharacteristic(MY_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID);

        // change value
        myCharacteristic.setValue("this is my value");

        // write
        bluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(myCharacteristic);
    }
}
```

now at this point it should jump into the **OnCharacteristicWriteRequest**  (server side!) callback where you can grab the new value

If this doesn't work, check on your server side if your bluetooth **advertiser** settings has the `.setConnectable(true)` set.

Also, check if you have your gatt server started with the correct service and characteristic.

Hope this helps